# Avoid ignoring next character after "/"

Tags: java, android, unicode

I am converting **unicode characters stored a String** into **unicode text**.

For example, here is a String -

```
String unicode = "\u0041\u006e\u0064\u0072\u006f\u0069\u0064";
```

Now from this string, I want to get separate unicode character -

```
u0041 u006e u0064 u0072 u006f u0069 u0064
```

So for that, I use the following code -

```
String[] parts = "\u0041\u006e\u0064\u0072\u006f\u0069\u0064".split("\");
```

But now since the `"` after `\` is ignored in `split("\")`, I am getting a error.

How to not ignore a character after `\`?

Comment: Your string doesn't contain any backslashes at the moment... it contains 7 characters. The *compiler* is converting the `\u....` into the relevant Unicode characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` character is an escape character. You are getting a syntax error because `\"` is the escape sequence for placing a `"` character in a `String` literal. To place a `\` inside a `String` literal, you need to use `\\` (the first `\` escapes the special meaning of the second `\`). So a syntactically correct statement would be:

```
 String[] parts = "\u0041\u006e\u0064\u0072\u006f\u0069\u0064".split("\\");
```

But that is not going to give you what you want, because the first argument does not contain any `\` characters. (Also, the `split()` method expects a regular expression and `\` is not a valid regular expression.) Instead, it contains seven characters with code points U+0041, etc. Perhaps you want:

```
 String[] parts = "\\u0041\\u006e\\u0064\\u0072\\u006f\\u0069\\u0064".split("\\\\");
```

or perhaps you want

```
 char[] parts = "\u0041\u006e\u0064\u0072\u006f\u0069\u0064".toCharArray();
```

and you can then convert each element of `parts` to a Unicode code point string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash. You also need to escape the backslash again because split() treats the string as a regular expression. Use `.split("\\\\");`

Comment: Did you test your answer?

Comment: `split("\\")` was not the only problem. Notice that OP will not have any ``\`` in String because each `\uXXXX` will be replaced by compiler with its corresponding Unicode character, so OP string actually is equal to `"Android"` (just print `System.out.println("\u0041\u006e\u0064\u0072\u006f\u0069\u0064");` and you will see what I mean).